# UIScrollView issues with UITableview

Tags: iphone

I have one UITableview and UICutsom cell. In that UITableview I populate data using web services. I change background color and font color of cell. When I scroll up and down of that Tableview cell background color and label color also change on another cells.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"FieldInventoryCell";

    // UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    FieldInventoryCell *cell=(FieldInventoryCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *nib=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FieldInventoryCell" owner:self options:nil];

        cell=[nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    NSArray *ar = [[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
    cell.Status.text=[ar objectAtIndex:1];
    cell.serialnumber.text=[ar objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.date.text=[ar objectAtIndex:2];

    if([cell.serialnumber.text isEqualToString:@"Grand Total"])
    {

       cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
        cell.serialnumber.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

    }
     if ([cell.serialnumber.text isEqualToString:@"INV_FLD Status Total"])
    {
        //cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
        cell.serialnumber.textColor=[UIColor orangeColor];

    }


    return cell;

}
```

Comment: You haven't described (or perhaps highlighted) what the actual problem is.  What problem are you facing?  What have you tried to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can understand from your post, the problem you're probably experiencing is connected with dequeuing cells. You're setting some colors for the contentView and the serial number label, but you're not resetting them if the conditions are not met. Since the table reuses cells, your already colored items will appear for new elements. To ammend the problem, reset the colors to default, i.e. something like

```
// ...
if([cell.serialnumber.text isEqualToString:@"Grand Total"])
{

    cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
    cell.serialnumber.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

} else {
    // reset color
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    cell.serialnumber.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
}

if ([cell.serialnumber.text isEqualToString:@"INV_FLD Status Total"])
{
    //cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
    cell.serialnumber.textColor=[UIColor orangeColor];

} else {
    // reset color
    cell.serialnumber.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
}
```